# Callkit not appear in low power mode in iPhone

Tags: ios, flutter, callkit

I'm using flutter_callkit_incoming, everything is working fine. But in iOS I'm facing an issue, the callkit doesn't appear if low power mode is enabled and app is in terminated or in background.

Flutter Version : 3.19.2
iOS Version: 17.4.1
flutter_callkit_incoming: 2.0.3

I checked the issues on GitHub as well but didn't found anything, so I reported this as an issue on the as well

https://github.com/hiennguyen92/flutter_callkit_incoming/issues/503

Comment: When you say “not appear”, I assume you’re just saying that incoming calls are not detected and handled when in [low power mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/101604)? I just wanted to clarify precisely what you meant by “callkit doesn’t appear”…

Comment: FWIW, this simply may be intended behavior, where the OS aggressively [shuts down](https://support.apple.com/en-us/101604) lots of background operations in order to save the battery. Other third-party apps suggest missing calls when in low power mode (e.g., the Signal app implies as much in their [Troubleshooting Calling](https://support.signal.org/hc/en-us/articles/360007060672-Troubleshooting-Calling) notes).